# How to create new connections using rally Webservice API

Tags: rally

I want to post a new connection to a user story via Rally API; but, I keep getting errors messages. what could I be doing wrong?

I tried using this API endpoint: 
 `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/changeset/create` with `Content-Type: text/plain`

```
{
  "Changeset": {
  "Message":"another test"
  }
}
```

and I got this response

```
{
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors": [
            "Validation error: Changeset.SCMRepository should not be null"
        ],
        "Warnings": []
    }
}
```

then I tried this below

```
{
  "Changeset": {
  "Message":"another test",
  "SCMRepository": {
    "ObjectName": "TestGithubRallyIntegration"
    }
  }
}
```

and got

```
{
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors": [
            "Cannot parse object reference from \"{\"SCMRepository\": {\"ObjectName\": \"TestGithubRallyIntegration\"}}\""
        ],
        "Warnings": []
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to do via cURL / Postman or etc.? UserStory is usually `HierarchicalRequirement`

Comment: PostMan! Yes, I noticed that of UserStory. I was trying to add a connection.

Comment: @user2738882 ![Connectors Sample](https://i.ibb.co/ggZHSJ0/Screenshot-2019-08-18-at-22-01-51.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a way out.

#### To Update/Create ChnageSet

uri: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/changeset/create

```
{
    "Changeset": {
        "Message":"another test",
        "Artifacts": {"Artifact":"/HierarchicalRequirement/<UserStory also known as HierarchicalRequirement>"},
        "SCMRepository": "/scmrepository/<Id>",
        "Revision":"1",
        "CommitTimestamp":"2018-08-18"
    }
}
```